# Rvalue references and SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11

I recently started using rvalue references and I've run into a case where I don't understand why they're working the way they are.

I'm trying to determine if a type can have `begin` and `end` called on it.  The below code gives the expected results if I change `foo` to take it's parameter by value or const reference, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work when using an rvalue reference and I was wondering if anyone could tell me why.

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class Container>
auto begin(Container &&c) -> decltype(c.begin()) { return c.begin(); }

template<class Container>
auto end(Container &&c) -> decltype(c.end()) { return c.end(); }

template<class T, size_t size>
T *begin(T (&array)[size]) { return (&array[0]); }

template<class T, size_t size>
T *end(T (&array)[size]) { return (&array[0] + size); }

template <typename T>
struct has_begin_end
{
    typedef char true_type;
    typedef char false_type[2];

    template <typename U> static true_type& test(decltype(begin(*((U*)0))) *b = 0,
                                                 decltype(end(*((U*)0))) *e = 0);

    template <typename U> static false_type& test(...);

    enum { value = (sizeof(true_type) == sizeof test<T>(0)) };
};

template<class T>
void foo(T &&t)
{
    std::cout << has_begin_end<T>::value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2};

    std::cout << has_begin_end<std::vector<int> >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_begin_end<int>::value << std::endl;

    foo(v);
    foo(123);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `*((U*)0)`, use `std::declval<U>()`.

Comment: Thanks GMan.  It seems I overlooked declval when reading about new c++0x features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because T gets deduced as an lvalue reference type when foo is called with an lvalue.  Try:

```
has_begin_end<typename remove_reference<T>::type>::value
```